Initial SessionFactory creation failed - org.hibernate.MappingException: An association from the table X refers to an unmapped class: Y
I am migrating application from Hibernate 4 to Hibernate 5.
I can't win with naming strategy. Of course I have already read:
hibernate ImprovedNamingStrategy overrides Table name in entity and ImprovedNamingStrategy no longer working in Hibernate 5
In hibernate.cfg.xml I have both:
<mapping resource="com/ubs/investor/cpss/domain/BonusHis.hbm.xml"/>
<mapping resource="com/ubs/investor/cpss/domain/Instrument.hbm.xml"/>

I already changed AnnotationConfiguration to Configuration and now I have:
private void reloadHibernateSessionFactoryFromConf(Map<String, String> prop) {
        try {
            sessionFactory = null;
            Configuration config = new Configuration(); //hibernate5

            for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry : prop.entrySet()) {
                config.setProperty(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
            }
            if(namingStrategy!=null){
                configuration.setNamingStrategy(namingStrategy); //code which I think spoil application
            }
            if(annotatedEntityPackages!=null){
                addAnnotatedClasses(config);
            }
            sessionFactory = config.configure().buildSessionFactory();
        } catch (final HibernateException e) {
            LOGGER.error("SessionFactory creation failed", e);
        }

and namingStrategy was put by:
<property name="namingStrategy">
            <bean class="org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy"/>
        </property>

I already tried to comment configuration.setNamingStrategy(namingStrategy); at all. I tried configuration.setPhysicalNamingStrategy(PhysicalNamingStrategyImpl.INSTANCE); but also CamelCase, UpperCase etc. and everytime error is the same. Whatever I do with this namingStrategy class won't be mapped.
Example class:
public class UpperCaseNamingStrategy extends PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl {

    @Override
    public Identifier toPhysicalColumnName(Identifier name, JdbcEnvironment context) {
        return context.getIdentifierHelper().toIdentifier(
                StringUtils.upperCase(name.getText(), Locale.ENGLISH));
    }

    @Override
    public Identifier toPhysicalCatalogName(final Identifier name, final JdbcEnvironment context) {
        return context.getIdentifierHelper().toIdentifier(
                StringUtils.upperCase(name.getText(), Locale.ENGLISH));
    }

    @Override
    public Identifier toPhysicalSchemaName(final Identifier name, final JdbcEnvironment context) {
        return context.getIdentifierHelper().toIdentifier(
                StringUtils.upperCase(name.getText(), Locale.ENGLISH));
    }

    @Override
    public Identifier toPhysicalSequenceName(final Identifier name, final JdbcEnvironment context) {
        return context.getIdentifierHelper().toIdentifier(
                StringUtils.upperCase(name.getText(), Locale.ENGLISH));
    }

    @Override
    public Identifier toPhysicalTableName(final Identifier name, final JdbcEnvironment context) {
        return context.getIdentifierHelper().toIdentifier(
                StringUtils.upperCase(name.getText(), Locale.ENGLISH));
    }

}

but still I can see in logs:
org.hibernate.MappingException: An association from the table BONUS_HIS refers to an unmapped class: domain.Instrument
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:709)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:746)
at repository.legacy.HibernateSessionManager.reloadHibernateSessionFactoryFromConf
So what is implementation of org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy in hibernate 5?
@Edit
Actually I used:
public class PhysicalNamingStrategyImpl extends PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl implements Serializable {

    public static final PhysicalNamingStrategyImpl INSTANCE = new PhysicalNamingStrategyImpl();

    @Override
    public Identifier toPhysicalTableName(Identifier name, JdbcEnvironment context) {
        return new Identifier(addUnderscores(name.getText()), name.isQuoted());
    }
   
    protected static String addUnderscores(String name) {
        final StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder( name.replace('.', '_') );
        for (int i=1; i<buf.length()-1; i++) {
            if (
                    Character.isLowerCase( buf.charAt(i-1) ) &&
                            Character.isUpperCase( buf.charAt(i) ) &&
                            Character.isLowerCase( buf.charAt(i+1) )
            ) {
                buf.insert(i++, '_');
            }
        }
        return buf.toString().toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT);
    }
}

and completely removed:
<property name="namingStrategy">
     <bean class="org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy"/>
</property>

but I don't think it's correct solutions because I can still see:
org.hibernate.MappingException: An association from the table BONUS_HIS refers to an unmapped class: domain.Instrument

Try following:

Correct Configuration:
// Set the Physical and Implicit Naming Strategies
config.setPhysicalNamingStrategy(new PhysicalNamingStrategyImpl());
config.setImplicitNamingStrategy(ImplicitNamingStrategyLegacyJpaImpl.INSTANCE);

Check Entity Mappings:


Ensure that all your entities are correctly annotated with @Entity and that all entity classes are registered in the configuration (i.e., listed in addAnnotatedClasses(config) or via config.addPackage("com.example")).
The error you see often comes up when Hibernate cannot find an entity or tries to map an association with a non-existent class.
Double-check that your mappings (tables, columns, and associations) are correct in your domain model.

Fix Entity Name and Table Name Mappings: If you are using custom table or column names, make sure that those match the table names generated by your PhysicalNamingStrategy

example:  @Table(name = "USER_ACCOUNT")
and your strategy converts userAccount to user_account, you will encounter issues unless the table is indeed named USER_ACCOUNT in the database.
Updated Code:
private void reloadHibernateSessionFactoryFromConf(Map<String, String> prop) {
    try {
        sessionFactory = null;
        Configuration config = new Configuration(); //hibernate5

        // Set properties
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : prop.entrySet()) {
            config.setProperty(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
        }

        // Set naming strategies
        config.setPhysicalNamingStrategy(new PhysicalNamingStrategyImpl());
        config.setImplicitNamingStrategy(ImplicitNamingStrategyLegacyJpaImpl.INSTANCE);

        // Add annotated classes
        if (annotatedEntityPackages != null) {
            addAnnotatedClasses(config);
        }

        // Build session factory
        sessionFactory = config.configure().buildSessionFactory();
    } catch (final HibernateException e) {
        LOGGER.error("SessionFactory creation failed", e);
    }
}


I have all of this and still get this error org.hibernate.MappingException: An association from the table BONUS_HIS refers to an unmapped class: domain.Instrument. Mapping should be okay because as I mentioned in Hibernate 4 they worked correctly. Is there a way to be sure that hibernate.cfg.xml is read? I guess I can't add sysout to hibernate.cfg.xml file. I changed to configuration.setImplicitNamingStrategy(ImplicitNamingStrategyJpaCompliantImpl.INSTANCE); but error is the same as with configuration.setImplicitNamingStrategy(ImplicitNamingStrategyLegacyHbmImpl.INSTANCE);

log4j.logger.org.hibernate=DEBUG Add this to check if you hibernate.cfg.xml is loading

Have you checked the mapping strategy? Not nessary to work with updated version if it is working with current one.

yes, I would consider not touching NamingStrategy but it was splitted into Physical and Logical in Hibernate 5 and NamingStrategy is removed. It will throw compilation errors so I had to change it.
Debugging is working, thanks!
What do you mean by mapping strategy? I have configuration in .xml and it was working in Hibernate 4 so I would like not touch it.

Read the point no. 3 in above answer. That is what strategy is. Or Ask GPT for research on this topic

ah, okay, I see. I did not touch any mapping, so all xmls are the same as in hibernate 4 and all @Entity annotations are also not touched. I found out that indeed chaning column names are not correct and removed toPhysicalTableName method. So it helps a bit but still see the error about unmapped class.
